# Usando group_concat com where no MySQL

Tags: mysql

estou com uma dificuldade em realizar uma consulta no MySQL em que eu consiga filtrar alguns resultados.

Minha estrutura de tabela está assim:

```
Client
+--------------------+
| id      |  name    |
+--------------------+
| 1       | client1  |
| 2       | client2  |
| 3       | client3  |
| 4       | client4  |
+--------------------+

Module
+--------------------+
| id      |  name    |
+--------------------+
| 1       | module1  |
| 2       | module2  |
| 3       | module3  |
| 4       | module4  |
+--------------------+

Client_Module
+-------------------------+
| client_id  | module_id  |
+-------------------------+
| 1          | 2          |
| 1          | 3          |
| 2          | 1          |
| 2          | 2          |
| 2          | 4          |
| 3          | 4          |
| 4          | 1          |
| 4          | 2          |
| 4          | 3          |
| 4          | 4          |
+-------------------------+
```

E minha query foi construída da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT     client.id, client.name, GROUP_CONCAT(module.id) AS modules
FROM       client
LEFT JOIN  client_module ON client_module.client_id = client.id
LEFT JOIN  module ON module.id = client_module.module_id
WHERE      client_module.module_id = 4 AND client_module.module_id = 3
group by client.id
```

A ideia da consulta é que ele me traga todos os clientes que possuem unicamente o módulo 3 e 4. Se minha consulta ali estivesse correta, o resultado que deveria aparecer seria apenas o cliente 4, somente somente ele possui os módulos 3 e 4.

Se eu uso o WHERE client_module.module_id IN (3,4) ele mostra um resultado onde todos os valores que contem 3 ou 4. Nesse caso o filtro precisa ser especifico para quem contenha o mesmo módulo.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c4889/57)

Coloquei o exemplo no SQL Fiddle.

Comment: SELECT     client.id, client.name, GROUP_CONCAT(module.id) AS modules
FROM       client
LEFT JOIN  client_module ON client_module.client_id = client.id
LEFT JOIN  module ON module.id = client_module.module_id
group by client.id
Having ( sum(case when module.id in (3,4) 
                       then 1 else 0 end) = 2
          And
          sum(case when module.id not in (3,4) 
                       then 1 else 0 end) = 0 )

Comment: Nesse caso provavelmente sai mais barato fazer um `JOIN module` pra cada módulo desejado (JOIN module a ... JOIN module b .... WHERE a.module_id = 3 AND b.module_id = 4 - [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/70) explica as diferenças dos tipos de join (no seu caso tem que ser um que só retorne quando todas as tabelas atenderem).

Comment: Depende também se é uma pesquisa avulsa ou algo que será dinâmico e constante , na 2@ hipótese uma solução melhor deverá ser pensada.

Answer (score -1):

Saulo, acho que a sua questão está um pouco confusa porque o cliente 4 também possui os módulos 1 e 2, mas para filtrar utilizando uma função de agregação utilize a cláusula Having depois do Group By:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(module.id) = '3,4'
```

**Edit**: na sugestão abaixo adicionei o Order By dentro da função Group_Concat para garantir a ordem dos valores

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(module.id order by module.id) = '3,4'
```

Considerando o seu exemplo e o tipo int da coluna id acho que também pode ser possível conseguir esse filtro utilizando a soma:

```
HAVING SUM(module.id) = 7
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Olá @imex Obrigado pela ajuda. Então, só para explicar melhor. Digamos que eu tenho clientes que usam vários módulos, Cliente 1 usa módulo 2 e 3, Cliente 2 usa o módulo 4, 1 e 2... e assim por diante. Preciso filtrar e que me mostre nos resultados apenas os clientes que usam o módulo 3 e 4 (juntos). Nesse caso dessa tabela apenas o cliente 4 possui os módulos 3 e 4 juntos. Exemplo disso é em uma consulta de veículos, primeiro eu quero filtrar carro que contenha Air Bag, depois eu quero somente carros que contenha Air Bag e Alarme. O que não tem os dois itens juntos, não aparece na consulta.

Comment: Testei com o HAVING e não funcionou =(

Comment: Editei a resposta acima para complementar a sugestão inicial e adicionar uma outra

Comment: Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:
WHERE client_module.module_id IN (3,4) group by client.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT module.id) = 2. Onde 2 é a quantidade de itens dentro do array (WHERE IN). Caso aqui fosse asssim: client_module.module_id IN (1,3,4) o final então seria = 3.
Obrigado pela ajuda. Se quiser postar ali como fiz: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c4889/153
Do outros modo citado, os números 3,4 teriam que estar na mesma sequencia do registro, se investe-se a consulta para 4 e 3 não funcionava.